# hintText color change in ios titanium

Tags: ios

I have developed an app for both android and IOS, but since my textfield color is grey in IOS, hintText is not visible..

I have an option in Android like hintTextColor(sdk version 4.1.0) and not in ios.I have tried adding the label to the field and changing the color,but this will be a problem for password field,where i am using password masking property.

I have also tried applying the custom Theme,but i didn't find any proper blog for ios custom theme..How do I change the hintText color in IOS?

Comment: Post some code and show us what you've tried

Comment: here what i did to change the hint color 
you need to create a textfeild and label with adding change listener on textfeild to show hint[https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121236/how-do-you-change-a-hints-color-in-a-text-field]  but the problem is this is not so efficient and it takes time to change the color and it is also problem for password field